# How do I increase the number of fuse worker threads?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fuse

I am starting up my fuse filesystem using fuse_main().  It is not starting with enough threads.  My filesystem is providing data to nginx and nginx is bottlenecking.  How do I increase the number of threads?

Comment: if you not mounted it as single threaded, it should dynamically allocate enough number of threads depending on number of messages from kext.